# Internal Python ID for first field in database

Tags: python

The following is part of my python script:

```
gp.CalculateField_management("parcs", "Apn", "[oldApnfield]")
```

The problem is that the field I am calculating from is going to be named something different in each shapefile, so I can't use the field name in the calculation.  Is there an internal ID that python uses to identify fields ?  What is the python language for saying "the first field in the database" instead of using the field name ?

Thanks for the help. I am very close, but now the calculation results with each row in the new field being PIDNUM instead of the value of PIDNUM.....

```
import arcgisscripting

# Create the geoprocessor object
gp = arcgisscripting.create(9.3)
gp.OverWriteOutput = True

# Set the workspace. List all of the folders within
gp.Workspace = "C:\ZP44"
fcs = gp.ListWorkspaces("*","Folder")

#
for fc in fcs:
    print fc
    gp.MakeFeatureLayer(fc + "\\Parcels.shp", "parcs") 
    fieldList = gp.ListFields("parcs")
    print fieldList[2].Name
    field1 = fieldList[2].Name
    print field1
    gp.CalculateField_management("parcs", "Apn", "[field1]")
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`ListFields`](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.2/index.cfm?id=830&pid=785&topicname=ListFields%20method&) to get the name of the field each time.